# Uniroot log(x) solution

Tags: r, math

I would like to find the root of log(x) = x<sup>2</sup> − 2 using `uniroot` in R

```
f <- function(x)  (log(x)+2-x^2)
uniroot(f, lower=0, upper=100000000)$root
```

But this shows the error

> Error in uniroot(f, lower = 0, upper = 1e+08) :    f() values at end
>   points not of opposite sign

Comment: `uniroot(f, lower=0, upper=1.5)$root`
[1] 0.1379341

Comment: @Headpoint Thank you so much :) Thats fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

[uniroot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/uniroot.html) requires an interval where the function has opposite signs at the two endpoints (since it uses a variation of the bisection method). It isn't a bad idea to do a quick plot when you don't know about just where to look:

```
f <- function(x)  (log(x)+2-x^2)
x <- seq(0.0,4,0.01)
y <- f(x)
plot(x,y,ylim = c(-1,1),type = "l")
abline(h=0)
```

This yields:

[image]

From this you can see that there are two roots, one between 0 and 1, and one between 1 and 2:

```
uniroot(f,interval = c(0,1))$root  #returns 0.1379346
uniroot(f,interval = c(1,2))$root  #returns 1.564445
```